# How to login into gitLab on browser for first time

Tags: gitlab

How to login into gitLab on browser for first time? other stackoverflow questions could't solve my problem.

[image]

**For example :**

```
**irb(main):002:0* user = User.find_by(username: "root")
=> nil**
```

Comment: There's an error somewhere within Gitlab when you're trying to sign in, this isn't an issue with your credentials. You'll have to provide more details on what's happening in order for us to help. If you can check the [log files](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/logs.html) and update your post to include any errors you see, it would help us answer this question.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question. and I see that there is no any user

Comment: Is there any output from `User.where(id: 1).first`? Also did you find any errors in the log files?

Comment: No error . It returns => nil

Comment: You may need to create the root user, though it's strange this didn't happen in the installation process. Here's a Cheat Sheet entry for creating users, though I'm not sure if it will work for the root user. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/troubleshooting/gitlab_rails_cheat_sheet.html#create-new-user